# ALTER INDEX ALL did not fix the problem, but deleting and recreating a non-clustered index does the trick. Why?

Tags: sql-server, statistics, index-maintenance

My SQL Server version is 2014.

The table has over 21 million rows.  One of its indexes is a non-clustered index on an integer field that is referenced a lot.

I did a mass update that affected about 20% of the rows.  It updated the values of that field. Since then, queries got really slow, so I performed:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON the_table REORGANIZE;
```

That did not do the trick even though `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` went down from anywhere between 30-90% to below 1%.

As a last resort, I deleted the troubling index and recreated it.  Now it's instant. So what good does `ALTER INDEX` do other than seemingly better average fragmentation percentages?

I did not update statistics prior to reorganising the index.

Comment: Do you have auto update statistics enabled? When almost 20% of the rows were changed, it should have been triggered by itself.

Answer (score 6):

`REORGANIZE` does a lot less than recreating the index. It does not change the data that is on each page, or update statistics, it just rearranges where the pages are stored.

What you are looking for is `REBUILD` which will do the same as dropping and recreating the index, with the exception of the fact that the index is never truly gone (during the rebuild the old index is used, it is only dropped when the new one is ready to replace it) so if you preform an `ONLINE` rebuild your applications can keep using the index (without giving the `ONLINE` directive the table will be locked during the rebuild). It will rearrange the data on the pages (removing internal space fragmentation not just fragmentation between pages) and recompute the stats.

You may not need the heavy lifting of a full index rebuild: just [recomputing the statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql) may have been sufficient for the case that you describe.

Another matter to consider is your `ALTER ALL` statement will also rebuild the clustered index of the table (if it has one) which could have significant implications depending on the queries being run.